# MVC 4 : Controller not found says WindsorControllerFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have this class `WindsorControllerFactory` which inherits from `DefaultControllerFactory`

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel _container;

        public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType)
        {
            if(controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Controller not found.");
            }
            return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;//exception here no controller found
        }
    }
```

in my account controller I have Login function
 [Authorize]

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {

            return View();

        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
//        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

when I run the application, `http://localhost:58383/Account/Login` I get error in that `WindsorControllerFactory` class, says controller not found. 
Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Did you register the controller installer in your application. The link: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx , should give a step-by-step insight into it. If you followed all the necessary steps as stated in the link, but still have problem, then please post complete code relating to the CastleWindsor setup, that you did.

Comment: Thanks i think that'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell to the mvc framework to use your windsor factory instead of the default one.

As per windsor documentation sample mentioned by Siva, I strongly suggest you to override ReleaseController as well...

You also need to register the controllers into the container.

I assume you set up properly the routing... that's nothing to do with windsor.

Answer (score 0):

You should register components first to Windsor Container.